# Parse error : syntax error, unexpected ')' in

Tags: plugins, php

I'm trying to install a new theme for a wordpress site and when I want to activate a plugin I get this error.
Can you help me understand how to solve this error?

```php
function thegem_cf_shortcode_settings()
{
    return array(
        'name' => __('Custom Fields', 'thegem'),
        'base' => 'gem_custom_fields',
        'icon' => 'thegem-icon-wpb-ui-custom-fields',
        'category' => __('TheGem', 'thegem'),
        'description' => __('Custom Fields', 'thegem'),
        'params' => array_merge(
            /* General - Layout */
            thegem_cf_set_layout_params(),

            /* General - Styles */
            thegem_cf_set_style_params(),

            /* Extra Options */
            thegem_set_elements_extra_options(),

            // Design Options
            thegem_cf_set_design_options_params(),

            /* Responsive Options */
            thegem_set_elements_responsive_options(),
            thegem_cf_extends_responsive_options_params(),
         
     )      
}

function thegem_cf_shortcode($atts, $content)
{
```

Comment: Check the error log, the stack trace should tell you exactly which lines of which PHP file the error is.

Answer (score 4):

You have a missing closing bracket on your `params` parameter on the `array_merge()`. It should look like this:

```php
    return array(
        'name' => __('Custom Fields', 'thegem'),
        'base' => 'gem_custom_fields',
        'icon' => 'thegem-icon-wpb-ui-custom-fields',
        'category' => __('TheGem', 'thegem'),
        'description' => __('Custom Fields', 'thegem'),
        'params' => array_merge(
            /* General - Layout */
            thegem_cf_set_layout_params(),

            /* General - Styles */
            thegem_cf_set_style_params(),

            /* Extra Options */
            thegem_set_elements_extra_options(),

            // Design Options
            thegem_cf_set_design_options_params(),

            /* Responsive Options */
            thegem_set_elements_responsive_options(),
            thegem_cf_extends_responsive_options_params(),
         ) // <-- missing this bracket
     ); // <-- missing semicolon
```

Comment: They're also missing a `;` at the end of the `return array( ... )` bit.